# How can I set my $_POST variables to be saved in $_SESSION forever?

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, database-connection

I have just planned to make a program where I need to connect USER's database using DBHost, DBUser, DBPassword and DBName to save the future needed values on MySQL server. 
For that, I have written such codes:

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

require('functions.php');
iq_add_style( 'DBConForm_Styles' , 'assets/scripts/css/iq_styles' , 'stylesheet' , 'css' );

function IQ_DB_Form(){
  ?>

  <form id="iq-dbconform" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <label>Server Host:&nbsp;<input type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="localhost" name="host-name" /></label>
    <label>Database User:&nbsp;<input type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="root" name="user-name" /></label>
    <label>Password:&nbsp;<input type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="User Password" name="user-pass" /></label>
    <label>Name of the Database:&nbsp;<input type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="developing_house" name="db-name" /></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Connect" name="dbconbtn" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="dbresetbtn" />
  </form>

  <?php
}
IQ_DB_Form();

// Database connection
$dbhost = $_POST['host-name'];
$dbuser = $_POST['user-name'];
$dbpass = $_POST['user-pass'];
$dbname = $_POST['db-name'];

$db_details = array(
    'host' => $dbhost,
    'user' => $dbuser,
    'password' => $dbpass,
    'dbname' => $dbname,
);
$IQcon = mysqli_connect($db_details['host'],$db_details['user'],$db_details['password'],$db_details['dbname']);



// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Looks like an Error connecting IQubex Database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Store Values in Session
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

echo $_SESSION['db-name'];
echo $_SESSION['user-pass'];
echo $_SESSION['user-name'];

// Perform queries
if ($IQcon){
mysqli_query($IQcon,"CREATE TABLE `Persons` (
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(255) NOT NULL,
);");
mysqli_query($IQcon,"CREATE TABLE `MadBoys` (
  `FirstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `Age` int(255) NOT NULL,
);");
mysqli_close($IQcon);
}
else{
  echo "There seems a problem with your server.";
}
?>
```

I have saved the Database Configuration Form Values in session so that when I write `echo $_SESSION['db-name']`, the inserted DB name is printed. But when the page is reloaded, going back coming again on the page, or something like that, all the values gets RESET! Thus, I don't want my users to end up connecting database again and again. I want it to be saved forever so that I can work for next program step.

Comment: still need help?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes, I need! But here there are so much formalities that I hate.

Comment: What do u mean formalities that u hate?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile My post got duplicated even if there was no answer given in the other posts :-( Anyways, if this post is opened, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if values are saved in session. If they are do not connect to db else get the values and save them in DB:

See the example below:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['stored-in-db']))
{
    //USE SESSION VALUES
}
else
{
$dbhost = $_POST['host-name'];
$dbuser = $_POST['user-name'];
$dbpass = $_POST['user-pass'];
$dbname = $_POST['db-name'];

$db_details = array(
    'host' => $dbhost,
    'user' => $dbuser,
    'password' => $dbpass,
    'dbname' => $dbname,
);
  $IQcon = mysqli_connect($db_details['host'],$db_details['user'],$db_details['password'],$db_details['dbname']);
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
  {
      $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
  }
  $_SESSION['stored-in-db] = true;
 }
```

Comment: You have syntax errors and you have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['stored-in-db]))` very wrong.. don't rush to answer coz you want to give solution first, get as much info as possible from OP

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
session_start();
```

at top of your pages where you are using sessions.

Comment: I actually want to save those values forever in session. I don't want to start any session unless I get those variables saved. :-)

Comment: @KumarAbhirup when u working with sessions u always need to have `session_start()` otherwise your session will be undifined

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile okay.. Got it. It is somehow working when I try connecting Session values and it connects database. But the form says that values are undefined. The issue is halfly solved and a great thanks for it. Can I know how to turn the Undefined values into saved once?

Comment: show me the error. When it occurs and how it looks like

Comment: when the user log's out the connection values will be lost, a frontend uiser trying to visit the site will get db connection error

Comment: of course it will. Its a session. Still dont get why trying to do that. And dont understand what he means by 'form says that values are undefined'. Which form? How it says?

Comment: just wait.. I will add those screenshots :-)

Comment: @KumarAbhirup dont use sessions to connect to db. Create a separated class for it, make a singleton, connect to db per need. Keeping it in session is impossible. Session starts to exists when you log out or when you close the browser. Cookies are more persistant, but again its a not do.

Comment: You really have a problem with me @Vladd I've said on the answer below dont rush to answer get as much info as possible this answer is incorrect

Comment: no @MasivuyeCokile i do not have any problem with you. I respect your efforts here to help out.

Comment: The form which is in the same PHP file. Just an HTML form which has an action of "ServerSelf".

Comment: Thanks you both. Your efforts are helping me a lot as i m just 13 years old and I m learning :-)

Comment: @KumarAbhirup it is nt possible to have session forever. Not that i am aware of. Session lasts as long as you are logged in, or until you close browser window. Then its destroyed and your form will show undefined when you open browser and go to the page again. You can stop throwing error by checking if isset(your variable)

Comment: Okay, then how do I get my program like WordPress DB configuration?

Comment: I was actually writing the code for that for u but the is question is closed, it can be opened by you editing the question and state what u want clearly @KumarAbhirup

Comment: I am not sure i understand what are you trying to achieve? You want  to make like some kind of installation process wher your user will create db, then connect to it and perform some queries? If so, what i told you will do. Just keep session_start() on top of every page and once user finish the last step, log him out

Comment: Hey @Vladd, I don't want to log anyone out because the website needs the information in database FOREVER without logging out. I don't want it like WordPress Login and Logout. I want to let users connect the db so that my further code can perform queries on it :-)

Comment: @KumarAbhirup you can ask a new question with what u want

Comment: I'm not able to do so. When I choose option for asking question, it is disabled for me by Fred. Atleast for next 4-5 days I can't post another question.